# Binomial expansion for $(x+a)^n$ for non-integer n

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

I finally figured out that you could differentiate $x^n$ and get $nx^{n-1}$ using the derivative quotient, but that required doing binomial expansion for non-integer values.

The most I can find with binomial expansion is the first, second, last, and second to last terms.

So how do I find something like $(x+a)^{\pi}$?  When differentiating in calculus, I didn't need to find terms after the second because I knew they would all cancel out, but how do you find these terms?

Do they work for negative exponents as well?

And does this work for complex exponents?

Which came first, Euler's method for complex exponents or binomial expansion for complex exponents?

Comment: How did you define $\pi$?

Comment: @flawr what do you mean?  I can tell you the second term is $a\pi x^{\pi-1}$.

Comment: supply x,n,a and the expression has an answer

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No, but could you give me full expansion formula for $(x+a)^{\pi}$?  And some arguments about negative/complex exponentials.

Comment: you need to define 'choose 3.14 objects from 76+3i objects' and it gets technical

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Oh goodness, I have no idea what you just said.  XD  Please explain more.

Comment: $\dbinom{7}{i}=\pi$ - i wish!

Comment: If your goal is to find the derivative of $x^a$ when $a$ is not a rational number, the simplest is to use $x^a = e^{a\ln(x)}$ and use the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Binomial theorem for any index $n\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x|<1,$ is

$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+\ldots$

For $(x+a)^\pi$ one could take $x$ or $a$ common according as if $|a|<|x|$ or $|a|<|x|$ and use Binomial theorem for any index. i.e., $x^\pi(1+a/x)^\pi$ in case $|a|<|x|.$

Comment: I'm confused.  How does the whole $n(n-1)(n-2)...$ work for non-integer $n$?

Comment: For eg. $(1+x)^{-1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots$ if $|x|<1.$ i.e., the series in the right hand sides converges to $(1+x)^{-1}$ if $|x|<1.$

Comment: No, but how does non-integer $n$ work for the numerator of the n-th term?  I know that series, but I can't define $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-\pi)$.

Comment: @SimpleArt: You just substitute. So if $n$ is equal to pi, then $\pi(\pi-1)(\pi-2)\dots$.

Comment: Oh... my bad.  I'm terribly sorry.  @TitoPiezasIII thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.\rule{0pt}{5mm}\pars{a + x}^{n}
\,\right\vert_{\ \verts{x/a}\ <\ 1}}\,\,\, =\
a^{n}\pars{1 + {x \over a}}^{n} = a^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\color{red}{\large\infty}}
{\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{k + 1}\Gamma\pars{n - k + 1}}
\pars{x \over a}^{k}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{k + 1}\Gamma\pars{n - k + 1}}
\, a^{n - k}\,x^{k}}} \\ &
\end{align}
By the way, $\ds{{\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{k + 1}\Gamma\pars{n - k + 1}} = {n \choose k}}$: It's the *generalized* binomial expression. When $\ds{n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq\ 0}}\,$, the factor $\ds{\Gamma\pars{n - k + 1}}$ truncates the sum at $\ds{n}$.