# Expansion of fraction

Tags: calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

Is there an expansion for
$$ (x+y)^p \approx x^p + y^p + \cdots $$
for $1<p<2$?

Comment: Apply the binomial theorem. Your first two summands are the first and the last summands at the binomial formula.

Comment: Is there a binomial theorem for non-integer exponents?

Comment: I hope this can help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584508/binomial-expansion-for-xan-for-non-integer-n/1584530

Comment: @myself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. The series $$(x+y)^{\alpha}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^{\alpha - k}y^{k},$$
where
$$\binom{\alpha}{k} = \frac{\alpha (\alpha - 1)(\alpha - 2) \dotsm (\alpha - k + 1)}{k!}.$$
converges for all $x,y\in \mathbb {R}$ with $x>0$ and $\left|{\tfrac {y}{x}}\right|<1$. In the special case $k=0$ we get an empty product, which is defined to be $1$.

*Reference:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: How do you define $x^{\alpha}$ for complex number? using branch cut?

Comment: @Sean No that's something different. You may use Eulers formula. Rewrite $x^{\alpha}$ as $e^{\alpha\log x}$. (In your question you don't need this, since you have $1<\alpha<2$.