evaluating ${}_1F_1(a;b;x)$ and $\Gamma(x)$ at negative arguments
I am trying to evaluate the following integral:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}^{\infty } u^{m+1} \left(u^2-\varepsilon\right)^{j+\frac{k}{2}-1} \exp \left(-\frac{u^2}{2 \varsigma}\right) du
\end{equation*}
With Mathematica's help, I get this to be:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\int_{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}^{\infty } u^{m+1} \left(u^2-\varepsilon\right)^{j+\frac{k}{2}-1} \exp \left(-\frac{u^2}{2 \varsigma}\right)\, du\\
&=\quad\frac12{\varsigma^{\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m)}} \Bigg(\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{k}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(-j-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{m}{2}\right) \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\varsigma}\right)^{\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m)}}{2\Gamma \left(-\frac{m}{2}\right)} {}_1F_1\left(\frac{m+2}{2};\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m+2);-\frac{\varepsilon}{2 \varsigma}\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+2^{\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m)} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m)\right) \, _1F_1\left(-j-\frac{k}{2}+1;-j-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{m}{2}+1;-\frac{\varepsilon}{2 \varsigma}\right)\Bigg)\end{split}
\end{equation*}
The Mathematica code is as follows:
Integrate[
 u ^(m + 1)*Exp[-(u^2)/(2*rho)]*(u^2 - eps)^(j + k/2 - 1) , {u, 
  Sqrt[eps], Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  m >= 0 && j >= 0 && k > 0 && Element[m | j | k, Integers] ]

The answer from Mathematica is:
 ConditionalExpression[
 1/(2 Gamma[-(m/2)]) \[Pi] Csc[
    1/2 (2 j + k + m) \[Pi]] (2^(1/2 (2 j + k + m)) rho^(
      1/2 (2 j + k + m))
       Gamma[-(m/2)] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[1 - j - k/2, 
       1 - j - k/2 - m/2, -(eps/(2 rho))] - 
     eps^(1/2 (2 j + k + m))
       Gamma[j + k/2] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[(2 + m)/2, 
       1/2 (2 + 2 j + k + m), -(eps/(2 rho))]), 
 Re[eps] > 0 && Im[eps] == 0 && Re[rho] > 0]

Surprisingly, the answer is in the form of Csc and Hypergeometric1F1Regularized, and in other invocations, in terms of Hypergeometric1F1 as provided above. I do not know when one shows up as opposed to the other, however, both are equivalent.
In the above, $m$, $k$ are all positive integers, and $j$ is a nonnegative integer.
The problem I seem to be having is how I evaluate this. The arguments of ${}_1F_1$ are sometimes negative here (see the second ${}_1F_1$, and for even $m$, it appears to me that $\Gamma(\frac m2)$ is undefined (has a pole).
It is true, however, that $\Gamma(\frac m2)$ in the denominator happens when there is a similar $\Gamma(-j-\frac k2-\frac m2)$ in the numerator. I am not sure how, or if, I can make use of this fact.
However, I find it confusing also how the second ${}_1F_1$ in Mathematica's integral can have a negative argument, given that per 13.2.3 of https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2 this does not exist for negative integer second arguments.
Any suggestions on what to do here to evaluate this? Thanks very much in advance!

As noted in the answer above, $\Gamma(x)$ isn't well-behaved for non-positive integers. However, the regularized form of $_1F_1(a;b;z)$ does have a limiting form for negative integer values of $b$, according to the DLMF, that may be appropriate:
By DLMF 13.2.5:
$$\lim_{b \to -n}\frac{{_1F_1}(a;b;z)}{\Gamma(b)}= {_1\bar{F}_1}(a;-n;z)=\frac{(a)_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}z^{n+1}{_1F_1}(a+n+1;n+2;z)$$
Where $(a)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol. It is also worth noting that if both $a$ and $b$ are negative integers, there is a solution if $a\geq b$:
$${_1F_1}(-n;-m;z)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{(-n)_kz^k}{k!(-m)_k}; \{n,m\} \in \mathbb{N};m\geq n$$
There are often also many ways to transform a hypergeometric function's arguments to make them more useful for calculation - The Wolfram Functions site has pages for both standard $_1F_1$ functions and regularized ${_1\bar{F}_1}$ functions, and if you're using Mathematica, any identity you find will also contain a version of the Identity as Mathematica Input, which should make it easy to play around with the various transforms at your own leisure.

Thanks very much for this @Lee Davis-Thalbourne. This is very helpful to see how ${}_1F_1$ can be calculated for a negative second argument. Btw, your referenced result can be used if n - m ? -.  The Gamma function for negative integers in the Mathematica result is now the unresolved issue.

It is worth noting that while $\Gamma(−n)$ is not well behaved, $\frac{1}{\Gamma(−n)}$ is - $\frac{1}{\Gamma(−n)}=0$, at least in the limit as $x \to -n$. If you are dealing with $\Gamma(−n)$ on the denominator, there's no real problem, and if it's on the numerator, find a way to move it to the denominator, and you can proceed forward.

I see, in that case, the first term is zero for even m, and only the second term prevails! Thank you!

By  some substitutions
 {du-> D[Sqrt[2 v]\[Sigma],v]dv,u->Sqrt[2 v]\[Sigma] , 
    {u,a_,\[Infinity]}:>     {v,(a \[Sigma]^2)/2,\[Infinity]}}

{{v, _ , \[Infinity]} :> {w, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  v -> w + (\[CurlyEpsilon] \[Sigma]^2)/2, dv -> dw}

your integral
 Inactive[Integrate][
 du u^(m + 1)* Exp[-(u^2)/(2*\[Sigma]^2)]*
    (u^2 - \[CurlyEpsilon]^2)^(j + k/2 - 1), 
   {u, \[CurlyEpsilon], Infinity}]

is of the form $$\int _0^{\infty }\text{dw} \sigma ^{m+2} e^{-\frac{\varepsilon  \sigma ^2}{2}-w} \left(\varepsilon  \sigma ^2+2 w\right)^{m/2} \left(\varepsilon  \left(\sigma ^4-\varepsilon \right)+2 \sigma ^2 w\right)^{j+\frac{k}{2}-1}dw.$$ Your result reflects the fact,  that the singularities for negative $m,n$ at $v=0,v=-\epsilon$  are not integrable for $(m,n)\ < \  -1+p,\ p \ > \  0$.
( the dummy du,dw factors serve as measure carrier inside the integrand for substitution)
Extracting the constant factors
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\varepsilon  \sigma ^2\right)} \left(\sqrt{2} \sigma \right)^{2 j+k+m}\right) \int _0^{\infty }e^{-w} \left(\frac{\varepsilon  \sigma ^2}{2}+w\right)^{m/2} \left(w+\frac{\varepsilon  \left(\sigma ^4-\varepsilon \right)}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)^{j+\frac{k}{2}-1}dw$$
So we can look for a standard integral
 $Assumptions = {\[Alpha], \[Beta]} > 0 && 
 {m, n} \[Element]  PositiveIntegers

$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-w} (w+\alpha )^{m} (w+\beta )^{n} \, dw$$
This integral doesn't evaluate in MMA 13 and is not known to Gradshteyn/Rhyzik, section definite integral, exponentials with rationals.

Thanks, what is the substitution that you have used here? I don't yet understand how this will help in my question for how to evaluate my integral for positive even integer $m$, or for evaluating ${}_1F_1$ for negative arguments. Could you please clarify? Thanks!

Edit your question to include the  Mathematica code for the integral and the result  (use the { } symbol in the edit toolbar) .  Retranslation from TeX is hard work.
In general, $\Gamma(-x)$ is well behaved except for simple  poles at 0 and the negative  integers by $$ (-x)! =(- x)  (-x-1)! \to  (-x) \Gamma(-x-2) = \Gamma (-x-1)$$
The substitutions: square the koppa $\to \sigma ^2$, and move the origin of $u \to u +\sqrt{\epsilon}$ and square $\sigma$

Thanks, edited above.

I implemented the result in Mathematica. For some reasonable choices of the parameters, as a function of u, the plot is flat zero, the same for Series upt to 7 elements. I suspect, that both hypergeometric series are the same with different signs. As a caveat: The definite integral routines in Mathematica vs 11+ are buggy. Perhaps to much AI and to little user control. Workaround: always test results numerically.

Thank you! In the last integral, how do you get that $m, n$ are integers? Are they not half-integers sometimes? But we can probably just do a binomial expansion of $(w+\alpha)^m(w+\beta)^n$ and then get an infinite series for when either m,n are not integers,and therefore an integral that is a series of Gamma functions. –

<There is a Laplace transform in Mathematica $$\mathcal{L}_x\leftx^{\beta } (x-a)^{\alpha }\right =\beta  \Gamma (\beta ) (-a)^{\alpha +\beta +1} U(\beta +1,\alpha +\beta +2,-a p)$$. The shift away from zero of $x^\beta \to (x-z)^\beta$ needs the indefinite integral, that can only be represented by products of binomials, infinite for non integer exponents.

Thanks again @Roland F.  What is U? The other confluent hypergeometric function? But why is is not possible to do a series expansion of $(w+\alpha)^m(w+\beta)^n$ and then we get a  double series of Gamma functions after the integration? Following:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584508/binomial-expansion-for-xan-for-non-integer-n which of course, means that we would get is a series of products and ratios of Gamma functions.
